# Problem with wifi in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

I'm not able to see (or access) my WiFi in Ubuntu.

```
tharcisyo@tssd:~$ iwlist scan
eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.
wlan0     Failed to read scan data : Network is down.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
tharcisyo@tssd:~$ sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```